# Fetch details of instances from cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Is it possible to fetch instances details like instances id, vpc id, key-pair, sg group etc from cloudformation template from cfn-get-metadata please assist.

If it possible please share ..

Answer (score 0):

cfn-get-metadata only gets info from the metadata section of the cloudformation template. In cfn-init, you can use values from params and maps.
You can use common cloud formation features to refer to the template like !FindInMap or you can use ${}.
Check out this snippet

```
          owner: !FindInMap [ nodes, !Ref nodeType, userName ]
          group: !FindInMap [ nodes, !Ref nodeType, userName ]
    configure:
      commands:
        configure_service:
          command: /opt/app/configure.sh
          test: "test ! -e /etc/systemd/system/${nodeType}.service"
```

If you need some data from the stack then you could add Outputs for the items you need and run describe stack in your user data.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name myteststack
```